python why is the conversion from HTML to PDF not working properly
I'm trying to create an invoice in A4 format dynamically using airium in python. The creation of the HTML page works as expected.

the porblem comes with the conversion to a .pdf, I tried many tools but the best results I had where with weasyprint, but a part of the invoice is cut out, and with pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf, but the invoice number move on it's own. How can I fix the issue, knowing that the HTML and the PDF must be to the A4 format and render the same no matter the file type ?
from weasyprint import HTML
path = "C:\\Users\\Administrateur\\data\\Dev\\"
input_html = path + "invoice.html"
output_pdf = path + "invoice.pdf"
HTML(input_html).write_pdf(output_pdf)

import pdfkit

path = "C:\\Users\\Administrateur\\data\\Dev\\"
input_html = path+"invoice.html"
output_pdf = path+"invoice.pdf"

path_wkhtmltopdf = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_file(input_html, output_pdf, configuration=config)


I don't see anything wrong about the place where the invoice number is located. Could you point us what the problem is? I also don;t see any part of the invoice cut down

it is under the company detail section creating a gap, instead of at it's right like on the HTML. See the hyperlinked images for the cut in weasyprint
